# Почему выдает выдает ошибку на строке с g += 1?

Tags: python

```
def remind():
    while True:
        g += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        
th = Thread(target=remind, args=())
```

Comment: В коде нигде не объявлено начальное значение `g`

Comment: Слова "выдаёт ошибку" должны сопровождаться текстом ошибки. А ещё лучше, сначала самостоятельно прочитать ошибку и постараться понять, в чем она заключается. Тогда, возможно, не придётся спрашивать в интернетах.

Comment: Вангую, что g - глобальная переменная, не объявленная таковой ))

Comment: Да, она была локальной, хотя я не знаю почему. Я создал переменную еще в начале кода. Разве она не должна была стать сразу глобальной?

Comment: Такой вопрос много раз задавался, нужно искать дубликаты. Пока вы только читаете переменную питон сам догадывается, что она глобальная. Как только вы её начинаете менять, питон считает, что она локальная и в функции нужна явная директива, что переменная глобальная.

Answer (score 3):

Запись вида `g += 1` это эквивалент записи `g = g + 1` Т.е. взять значение из переменной **g**, увеличить на 1 и запись в **g**

А в вашем случае переменная **g** нигде не объявленна и неинициализирована. И в результате итерпретатор ругается на то что он не знает какое значение использовать.

Чтобы убрать эту ошибку нужно инициализировать переменную **g**. Например добавить перед while строку `g = 0` в том случае если эта переменная будет у вас использоваться только внутри функции.